# Cordova file plugin error after install

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I got this error after installing the `cordova-plugin-file` package that I can't really understand. The error apparently raises from another package that might have installed at the same time as a sort of dependency (`cordova/filetransfer`):

```
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJava
apache/cordova/filetransfer/FileTransfer.java:59: error: package org.apache.cordova.file does not exist
import org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils;
                              ^
apache/cordova/filetransfer/FileTransfer.java:912: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
                        ^
  symbol: class FileUtils
cordova/filetransfer/FileTransfer.java:912: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
```

One of the files is importing `org.apache.cordova.file` which does not exist. Any ideas?

This is a meteor project and I installed it using the following command:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-file-transfer@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git#189942284a64fb3de11e81f3fb41af4e102b1ac6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have used multiple version plugins or let's say your app was build in lower version and you have installed the plugin of the higher version.
So just uninstall the higher version package or plugin and install it with specific version or downgrade or upgrade your project itself.
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue today.

In my case, the cordova-plugin-file was "skipped" during the configuration of the android platform, because Cordova (5.4.0) using cordova-android 4.1.0 was not able to use it (the plugin now requires at least cordova-android 5.0.0dev).

To fix this, follow the procedure given by Cordova [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/09/cordova-android-5.0.0.html):

```
cordova platform update android@5.0.0
```

Tested & working with an Ionic project (which had the same issue).

(NB: I had to do a "platform remove" of android, and then a "platform add" using android@5.0.0)

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem in the platform directory (especially if you've been upgrading plugins). In that case it can be solved by removing and re-adding the android platform.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```